# collasping and expanding LinearLayout instead of TabLayout inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have used LinearLayout instead of Tablayout inside  AppBarLayout. Please first watch this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=enWVNP3Gifg).

I want the same collapsing and extending effect for this LinearLayout as TabLayout has (in this video) when scroll event occurs. I also want toolbar to
to be fixed on the top.  just Like the video demo.

My code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.activities.ViewPagerSlider">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Toolbar title"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="collapse and expands text"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <com.xxx.activities.extras.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is it possible to do as I want?